# Is this equation on exponentiation true?

Tags: exponentiation

Is the below equation true for all real values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$? (with $c\neq0$)

$$d(a+b)^c= (ad^{1/c}+bd^{1/c})^c$$

Some cases has been tested and the above has not been disproved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails for $c=1/2$, $d=-1$, $a,b=1$, since then
$$ d(a+b)^c=-2^{1/2}=-\sqrt2\neq\sqrt2=(ad^{1/c}+bd^{1/c})^c=2^{1/2}$$
However, it is valid (and both sides are defined) whenever the bases of exponentiation are positive: when $d>0$ and $a+b>0$. This is because $ab^x=a^xb^x$ and $(a^x)^y=a^{xy}$ are valid for real $a,b>0$ and real $x,y$, so that the RHS can then be rewritten $$(ad^{1/c}+bd^{1/c})^c=(d^{1/c}(a+b))^c=(d^{1/c})^c(a+b)^c=d^1(a+b)^c=d(a+b)^c.$$

Comment: you are right. Thank you. I deleted my post

Comment: The convention is that $x^{1/2}$ is the positive square root of $x$ when $x>0,$ so if $y<0$ then $y\ne (y^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @user254665: Is that supposed to confirm or contradict (or question?) something that I said in my answer?

Comment: It was not to contradict, but was attempt to clarify why your counter-example works: $d\ne (d^2)^{1/2}$ when $d<0$.